# Mysql query to avoid negative symbol in the output table

Tags: sql, mysql

Here I have query in which I am trying to avoid the negative symbol in the final output. But why do I get that negative symbol ?
I have try to use the replace() but it doesn't work.
can you please help me with this ?
here is the query ..,

```
WITH Partitioned AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, start_date ORDER BY customer_id, start_date) AS RowNumber
    FROM data_bank.customer_nodes
) 
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN RowNumber > 1 THEN 0
        ELSE COALESCE(DATEDIFF( (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM data_bank.customer_nodes WHERE start_date < a.start_date AND customer_id = a.customer_id), a.start_date), 0)
    END AS Days_between
FROM Partitioned a
```

Here is the output I got from above query

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `partition by` in `Over` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: "DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from
one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
calculation." (see: [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)), so switch the two parameters to make sure the first date is after the second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH Partitioned AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, start_date ORDER BY customer_id, start_date) AS RowNumber
    FROM data_bank.customer_nodes
) 
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN RowNumber > 1 THEN 0
        ELSE GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(a.start_date, COALESCE((SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM data_bank.customer_nodes WHERE start_date < a.start_date AND customer_id = a.customer_id), a.start_date)))
    END AS Days_between
FROM Partitioned a;
```

Here, I've modified the CASE statement to calculate the difference as the maximum of 0 and the result of DATEDIFF. This way, even if the subquery's result is greater than the current start_date, the negative value will be replaced by 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are subtracting the larger date from the smaller date, so it's showing negative number. Change the positions of `a.start_date` and `(SELECT MAX(start_date)...)` in the `DATEDIFF` function to ensure that you're subtracting the smaller date from the larger date.

```
WITH Partitioned AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, start_date ORDER BY customer_id, start_date) AS RowNumber
    FROM data_bank.customer_nodes
) 
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN RowNumber > 1 THEN 0
        ELSE COALESCE(DATEDIFF(a.start_date, (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM data_bank.customer_nodes WHERE start_date < a.start_date AND customer_id = a.customer_id)), 0)
    END AS Days_between
FROM Partitioned a;
```

Answer (score 1):

When first argument of `DATEDIFF` is smaller than the second argument, then you get negative result. I.e. second argument is subtracted from first argument to get date difference in days.
You can use `ABS()` function of mysql to convert negative values to unsigned values, as folllows:

```
ABS(
  COALESCE(
    DATEDIFF(
      (
        SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM data_bank.customer_nodes 
          WHERE start_date < a.start_date AND customer_id = a.customer_id
      ), 
      a.start_date
    ), 
    0
  )
)
```

NOTE: I have only shared relevant portion of the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

in `ROW_NUMBER` `Over` clause, you are using `PARTITION BY customer_id, start_date`. Which is returning all row numbers as 1. `Partition by` is creating segments for same value combinations of `customer_id` and `start_date`. Row number restarts from 1 for each segment. Since all value combinations are unique, hence each segment has only one row and hence row number for each row is 1.

Hence your `WHEN RowNumber > 1 THEN 0` is not entering, because it always get 1 as `RowNumber`.

You can remove `Partition BY` clause and it will also fix your issue.